# SQLException was unhandled - Windows CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, windows-ce

I'm using a class I created to connect to the SQL Server 2008 R2 Database. Using WPF and Windows Forms on Desktops, the connection worked fine. However, using Windows CE, it's a totally different story.

The Exception being thrown is SQLException, with no error. Quite odd, especially due to the fact that according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.90).aspx) MSDN page, under Remarks, all SQLException(s) should have an SQLError.

Here's the code:

```
private void Open(string password)
    {
        //try
        //{
            connection = "Data Source=" + SERVER + "; Initial Catalog=" + DATABASE + "; User ID=" + USERNAME + "; Password=" + password + ";";

            connect = new SqlConnection(connection);
            connect.Open();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Connection Error");
        //}
    }
```

Attached you should find a screenshot.

[image: Error]

UPDATE 1:
[image: Error Details]
[image: References]

I'm currently using 'System.Data.SQLClient'.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: do you have requisite DB client libs loaded in WinCE?

Comment: What libraries do you use to connect to the sql server?

Comment: Could you click on "View Details" and check error message and inner exception?

Comment: I updated the question satisfying all of your queries. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this happening in a simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: Simulator haven't tested it on a device yet.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the part that states "...with no error". Looking at the screenshot, I see a Class (severity) of 20, indicating a problem with the statement, and the Number 6, which you could look up in master.dbo.sysmessages to get more information. Or is it that you are just looking for a more informative Message than "SqlException"?

Comment: @CarstenHansen The latter.

Comment: It seems to work fine at my end, using CE 7.0 and .NET CF 3.5 - at least I get a sensible Message when trying to connect to a non-existing server. At first I thought it might have something to do with debugging string resources not being included in the CE image, but it works both with and without SYSGEN_DOTNETV35_SR. Which version of CE and .NET CF are you using? Is it your own, custom CE platform? Could you try with a non-existing SERVER and see if you get a Message then? (just to see if it is this specific error that doesn't have a Message string)

Comment: I'm using CE 5.0, since the PDAs run 5.0 and 6.0. The .NET Framework being used is 3.5 as well. I'll give it a shot thanks.